# unable to select an element using xpath in selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I've been trying to select an element by xpath and display it but I get an error everytime I try to run the code. I got the xpath by doing inspect element and copying full xpath yet it gives me the error. It's a dynamic form too, so I can't choose the direct text and I would probably need to use an address to locate that element as it changes everytime but I've not been able to select that certain element. how do I choose the element?

this is how I tried to choose the element

```
name_from_doc=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()[1]')
print(name_from_doc)
```

the error that I get is

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I want to store the name of the person separately and address separately in two different variables

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value `NAPERVILLE IL` Use follwoing xpath to get the element and then use `splitlines()` and last index value.

```
name_from_doc=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(.,"Billing Address")]/following::div[1]').text
print(name_from_doc.splitlines()[-1])
```

**Update**:

```
name_from_doc=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(.,"Billing Address")]/following::div[1]').text
print(name_from_doc.splitlines()[0])
print(name_from_doc.splitlines()[1])
print(name_from_doc.splitlines()[-1])
```

Comment: I want to get the name of the person too? how do I do that?

Comment: and the other address too.. what is splitlines is doing?

Comment: @reduxHelpPlz: this will split lines if the text having any lines in your care `<br>` are nothing but lines.

Comment: is there any way through which I could get only the first two numbers instead of the whole address in the second line? i mean now it would print `10 MUIRHEAD` but I only needed the 10 and not muirhead

Comment: Sorry mate it’s too late here in UK.Shall I comeback tomorrow.See if you can do that take the second print statement in a variable such as ele and then split.  print  ele.split(“ “)[1]

Comment: yeah no problem. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Alternative. Get the value directly with XPath. `substring-before(normalize-space(//div[contains(.,"Billing Address")]/following::text()[normalize-space()][2])," ")` Output : `10`

Answer (score 1):

As the `Billing Address` text would always be there, so can reach there by using its text in the xpath and then find its exact value by using `following` in the xpath.
You can do it like:

```
name_from_doc = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Billing Address')]//following::div[1]//br[2]")
print(name_from_doc.text)
```

Comment: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@text,'Billing Address')]//following::div[1]//br[2]"}` got this error

Comment: @reduxHelpPlz have edited my answer, had mistake a mistake in the last one. Please pick the latest answer.

Comment: didn't get any error but nothing shows in the display!!